# Create new "execute" function/program in Windows (instead of command prompt)

Tags: windows, command-prompt, youtube-dl

I am using a small program called [Youtube-DL](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html) to download videos but everytime I have to open the command prompt, get to the right folder and then execute, say, `youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFk0mgljtns`.

What do I need to set up so that I can do the same thing directly from the "execute" tool (the one you access with the shortcut Windows+R)? Ideally all I would need to do would be Windows+R, type `yt-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFk0mgljtns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the youtube-dl executable to your [%path%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)): Use `setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\folder_with_youtubedl"` with an admin cmd.

Comment: I actually used [this guide](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to add the folder to the %path% (you might want to add it in your answer), having the folder in the %path% did the job thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you can also use the GUI to configure your path. Happy to help.